# Is it possible to work out kinetic energy without knowing mass?

Tags: energy, kinematics

I know the speed of the object, but not the mass. I know that it is not a photon and not travelling at the speed of light . Is it possible for me to work out the kinetic energy from this information?

Answer (score 2):

Would you expect a feather and a car traveling at the same speed to have the same kinetic energy? You need some piece of information to differentiate between these cases and since they have the same speed it can't be that. So yes you do need the mass, or something that lets you work out the mass, to work out an object's kinetic energy from its speed

Answer (score 0):

The kinetic energy of a non-rotating object of mass $m$ travelling at speed $v$ is

$\frac{1}{2} m v^2$

so you need to know the mass, but you don't have that information.

Comment: In special relativity it's $mc^2((1-v^2/c^2)^{-1/2}-1)$, but the same "no, you need the mass to which it's proportional" implication remains.

Comment: @J.G. I should have written "Newtonian calculation".

Answer (score 0):

Not from the information given. But if the object collides with a known mass, you can measure the resulting velocities and draw conclusions.

Momentum is conserved. You can solve for $m_u$.
$$m_u \vec{v_{ui}} = m_u \vec{v_{uo}} + m_2 \vec{v_{2o}}$$